# Excel VBA: Error Handling Breaking Mid-Code

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

Code loops through a massive amount of data performing calculations. Goes well for first two workbooks. Third workbook, suddenly Error Handling breaks--no longer works. Ideas on why?

1)  `Break on Unhandled Errors` is correctly marked in options

2) Each Error Handling is followed by On Error GoTo 0

3) This breaks in On Error Resume Next AND in On Error GoTo ErrHandler.

I thought OERN disregards any other error handling anyway?

Here is the lengthy code. I took out several of the variable definitions to shorten it.

```
amount = lastcolumn / 6
totalstrikes = 0
Do Until amount = 0
    currentcolumn = amount * 6 - 5
    i = 2
Do Until Sheets("Data").Cells(i, currentcolumn).Value = ""
    currentminute = Sheets("Data").Cells(i, currentcolumn).Value
    If oldminute <> 0 Then
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        If WorksheetFunction.MRound(currentminute - oldminute, 1 / 86400) >= 0.0007 Then
            'Do Stuff
        End If
5        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
        Do Until Sheets("Data").Cells(i, currentcolumn) <> currentminute
        If InStr(1, hitlist, Sheets("Data").Cells(i, currentcolumn + 1).Value) = False Then
            totaltime = totaltime + CSng(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, currentcolumn + 4).Value)
            totaltotal = totaltotal + CSng(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, currentcolumn + 2).Value)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    On Error Resume Next
    If totaltime / totaltotal <= failuretime Then
        Strike = 1
    Else
        Strike = 2
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    If minute1 = 0 Then
        'do stuff with the minutes
    End If
    oldminute = currentminute
Loop
amount = amount - 1
Loop
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
If WorksheetFunction.MRound((-1 * (currentminute - oldminute)), 1 / 86400) >= 0.0007 Then
    Resume Next
Else
    GoTo 5
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put `Err.Clear` before `Resume Next`.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you have that many `On Error` statements in a function this small, you need to consider refactoring your code. Over-reliance on `GoTo` and `Resume` leads to spaghetti code, difficult to read and maintain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it this way and manage your run-time errors:

```
If WorksheetFunction.MRound(currentminute - oldminute, 1 / 86400) >= 0.0007 Then
    'Do Stuff
End If
```

...or without needing to manage run-time errors, by dropping `WorksheetFunction` and instead testing the function's return value for an error:

```
Dim m
m = Application.MRound(currentminute - oldminute, 1 / 86400)
If IsError(m) Then
    m = Application.MRound((-1 * (currentminute - oldminute)), 1 / 86400)
End If
```

Comment: Does it not bother anyone that VBA has no "Mround" function? That the correct syntax is `Application.Worksheetfunction.Mround(...` or just `Worksheetfunction.Mround(...`, but not  `Application.Mround(...` ?